# TypeORM: How to use find() with a WHERE clause using AND(OR(value1, value2), value3)?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using `TypeORM 0.3.17` and I'm trying to make a query using the `find()` method with a WHERE clause that combines AND and OR operators. Specifically, I need to create a query with the following structure: `AND(OR(value1, value2), value3).`

*It doesn't work that way, but here is an example of how it should look like:*

```
const photoRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Photo)
const photos = await photoRepository.find({
  where: AND(
    [{ name: query }, { location: query }],
    { status: Status.Active }
  )
})
```

Is there a way of doing this using the `find()` method and **not using the QueryBuilder**?

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
const photoRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Photo)
const photos = await photoRepository.find({
    where: [
        { name: query, location: query }, // name AND location
        { status: Status.Active } // OR status
    ]
})
```